# AWS Amplify Authenticator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using AWS authenticator to log users in to my app. I would like to create a button inside a view in the application to log users out but I'm unsure how to push this up to the entry layer.

The current entry layer code works, how can I amend it such that the logout function sits within 'MainView'.

I want it to essentially show:
*if logged in show main view

otherwise show the default Authenticator sign up logic*

Im new to this so any help would really help me learn. Thank you all

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Authenticator { state in
                //                MainView()
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello, \(state.user.username)")
                    Button("Sign out") {
                        Task {
                            await state.signOut()
```